# How to deal with historical data in Marketing Mix Model?

Tags: regression

I am trying to learn Marketing Mix Modeling and have advertising data for about 1.5 year. But I also have revenue data going back ~5 years in the complete absence of any advertising.

What dataset makes more sense to analyze in your opinion?

Dataset A (lots of zeroes for advertising)

Sales    Time   Advertising
100        1.        0
110.        2.       0
120.       3.        50

Dataset B (no zeroes for advertising)

Sales    Time   Advertising  Historical sales (eg, 1 yr ago)
120       3.        50.                 110
140.      4.        75.                  110

I have tried analyzing both data sets using linear regression, but don’t know which results to believe. They both seem plausible.